# VS code Expected identifier, got 'LParen'solc

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler, visual-studio-code, warnings

I keep getting this error/warning on my vscode when I emit events and build constructors.

[image]

or

[image]

After a bit of googling I understand it is something about my compiler, since solc <0.4.18 does not support these features. [This thread](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/939) says I have to update truffle to fix this problem. Although, I'm not using truffle at all. I have

```
"solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1",
```

on my vscode settings and on my terminal I have

```
> $ solc --version 
> Version: 0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.Linux.g++
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please try to compile your contract using `solc` in terminal and provide the compiler's output. Seems like VS code does not support new syntax (may be you should update it).

Comment: It works fine. No errors. the normal outcome.
There are several outputs depending on the flags, which one do you want? --ast ? --abi? --bytecode?

Comment: Which plugin are you using in VS Code? I've Juan Blanco's solidity and it works without issues.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same one. Everything works fine except for this warning. It's wired. It's like syntax checker is trying to use an older version of solc , although I don't know how to change it. Cause I trying changing the setting and it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had a similar error, then I realized the culprit in this case was in fact [image]a malfunctioning VS Code plugin not Solidity nor truffle. Please check your plugins list in VS Code and see if one of your plugins is called "Solidity Extended" by beaugunderson and disable it.